# How do you stop a React application failing if a key doesn't exist in object or array?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object, error-handling, key

How can I check whether a key exists before iterating through an array with .map?

```js
    import React from 'react';
    ReactDOM.render(

        myObj={
          "meat": {"main": ["Chicken", "Beef", "Lamb", "Pork"]}
        }

        const Dinner () =>{
        const course = 'main';
           return(
              <div>
                  //course might result in a lookup that doesn't exist
                  {myObj.meat[course].map((n) => n + '')}
              </div>
       );
    }
    export default Dinner;
    );
```

Because the key (course) is a variable, it could result in a lookup that doesn't exist e.g. myObj.meat['sillyKey'] and this is causing my application to fail. How do I stop the application failing in this case?

Many thanks,

Katie

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a safeguard as follows:

`{myObj.meat[course] && myObj.meat[course].map((n) => n + '')}`

Comment: Thank you BerndS for your reply. I love how simple that looks. The trouble is I'm getting the error "Cannot read property 'course' of undefined. Perhaps I've simplified my object too much in my explanation? It's actually more like myObj={ "meat": {"main": {"Monday":["Chicken", "Beef","Lamb", "Pork"]}}} So it's trying to find myObj.meat[course]Monday. Could it be a problem to have something coming after [course]?

Comment: Do you perhaps try to access the attribute using myObj.meat.course in your code instead of myObj.meat[course]? I don't see how that error can come from the code you posted in your question unless the constant course === "course".

Comment: Thanks BerndS - no, I've checked to see if I've put quotes in and I've done it correctly. Just to test it's not that I have tried hard coding the wrong value into the course bit, as follows: {myObj.meat['notThere']["Monday"] && myObj.meat['notThere']["Monday"].map((n) => n + '')} This doesn't work. But when I hard code in the correct value e.g. myObj.meat['main']["Monday"] this does work. Any ideas?

Comment: If you paste this into the browser console, it works:      myObj={ "meat": {"main": {"Monday":["Chicken", "Beef","Lamb", "Pork"]}}}  {myObj.meat['main']['Monday'] && myObj.meat['main']['Monday'].map((n) => n + '')}        But this does not: 
   myObj={ "meat": {"main": {"Monday":["Chicken", "Beef","Lamb", "Pork"]}}}{myObj.meat['TEST']['Monday'] && myObj.meat['TEST']['Monday'].map((n) => n + '')}

Comment: You'd have to use an additional guard: `{myObj.meat['main'] && myObj.meat['main']['Monday'] && myObj.meat['main']['Monday'].map(... `

This can become cumbersome for nested structures. Maybe consider using the Lodash `get` function. https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#get

Comment: Thanks BerndS - I am a bit of a noob at this but will read up on how to implement that. Thanks again!